# Parsing the response using REST vs. SOAP API in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rest, soap

I am trying to parse a response that I receive using Rest API calls, but get an error when I say, something like: response.body.first[1]. I am transferring Soap API calls to rest API calls. Is response.first something that can only be used in Soap, if so what is the equivalent in Rest? Here is the code snippet that I am having trouble with:

```
url = @@rest_base_url.to_s + "filters/#{id.to_s}/results"
resource = RestClient::Resource.new url, @username, @password
  response = resource.get
  data = JSON.parse(response.body)["data"]
if response.body.first[1][:return].nil?
  requirements = nil
elsif response.body.first[1][:return].is_a?(Array)
  # puts "|get_requirements| req is an array".blue
  requirements = []
```

Thank you

Comment: This question needs a lot more detail. What do you mean by "transferring Soap API calls to REST API calls"? What client libraries are you using? Can you give us sample code that is causing the error, and can you share the error message?

Comment: The project that I am working on, is a web application which currently uses a Soap client, and uses Soap API calls to get specific information off of Jama (Which is a management tool). Look at the above post, I edited to include the code. The library that I am using is rest-client...if that is what you are asking.

Comment: You cannot use a REST client to interact with a SOAP service. You'll need a dedicated SOAP client like [Savon](http://savonrb.com/).

Comment: Ya that is my project, I have to get rid of the the SOAP service and start using the Rest service. Savon, is used currently, but I need to get rid of Savon and use a Rest service.

Comment: So there's a REST service? I'm not familiar with Jama, but there's no guarantee that there is a straightforward "mapping" from one service to another. You'll need to refer to the REST documentation for its interface.

Comment: Yes there is a REST service, ya that's the hard part since there is no way to really map from SOAP to REST. Anyways thank you for your help, appreciate it.